# Edges from Bones Script

Tags: rigify

Can anyone verify that this script works in 2.78?

```
import bpy
# ACTUAL FUNCTION THAT TURN BONES INTO EDGES 
def boneToEdges(armature_name='metarig'):

   myRig = bpy.data.objects[armature_name]

   # which armature to work on
   #myRig = bpy.data.objects['Armature']
   #myRig = bpy.data.objects['metarig']

   # this actually return STRING NAME of bone
   boneNames = myRig.data.bones.keys()

   # the actual data to each 
   myBones = myRig.data.bones

   for i, bone in enumerate(myBones):
       #print(bone.name, bone.vector)
       # every bone has HEAD and TAIL

       #loc = bone.vector
       head_loc = bone.head_local
       tail_loc = bone.tail_local

       createEdge(coord1 = head_loc, coord2 = tail_loc)
boneToEdges("MyArmature") # Change the name to your Armature Object Name.
```

Sources:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVVFO-Lw4XA&t=155s
http://blendersushi.blogspot.com.au/2013/06/python-skin-bone.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work as you have it posted, you're missing some code. I can confirm that this code works in 2.78:

```
import bpy
def createEdge(coord1 = (-1.0, 1.0, 0.0), coord2 = (-1.0, -1.0, 0.0)):

    Verts = [coord1, coord2]
    Edges = [[0,1]]

    profile_mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("Edge_Profile_Data")
    profile_mesh.from_pydata(Verts, Edges, [])
    profile_mesh.update()

    profile_object = bpy.data.objects.new("Edge_Profile", profile_mesh)
    profile_object.data = profile_mesh

    scene = bpy.context.scene
    scene.objects.link(profile_object)
    profile_object.select = True

# ACTUAL FUNCTION THAT TURN BONES INTO EDGES 
def boneToEdges(armature_name):
    myRig = bpy.data.objects[armature_name]

    # which armature to work on
    #myRig = bpy.data.objects['Armature']
    #myRig = bpy.data.objects['metarig']

    # this actually return STRING NAME of bone
    boneNames = myRig.data.bones.keys()

    # the actual data to each 
    myBones = myRig.data.bones

    for i, bone in enumerate(myBones):
       #print(bone.name, bone.vector)
        # every bone has HEAD and TAIL

        #loc = bone.vector
        head_loc = bone.head_local
        tail_loc = bone.tail_local

        createEdge(coord1 = head_loc, coord2 = tail_loc)
boneToEdges("Armature") # Change the name to your Armature Object Name. "
```

Comment: Thanks Cmomoney! I figured I was doing something wrong. Works perfectly now. Cheers!